# duplicate label based on a value in a subreport in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Quite new to Crystal Reports here.

I have a label report that contains several subreports on different details rows. One of those subreports could have multiple values, and right now the label report spits on the values on the same label, one after the other. Is there a way to have the label create separate labels if that subreport spits out multiple values?

Comment: Do it in formula.

Comment: complext question.. please simplify or atleast post some data